# Printing Text from Power Shell

Tags: clojure, ms-word, google-docs, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

In the Windows power shell I run `lein repl` and then evaluate some Clojure functions that I have written. The functions output large matrices or vectors that are not easily transcribed by hand. This is why I'd like to be able to copy the data from the REPL, if that is possible, or find some way to quickly transfer the data to a word document or Google doc. Is there a way to copy the output from these functions out of the REPL to a document, or some means that the output can be "copy and pasted"?

Comment: Please explain REPL in the context of your question.

Comment: @RSahu He said: "lein repl"

Comment: @Chiron that part was edited in after the question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Automatic cut-and-paste from and to the REPL**

Have a look at Sean Devlin's [clipboard utilities](https://github.com/francoisdevlin/devlinsf-clojure-utils/blob/master/src/lib/sfd/clip_utils.clj). It has functions that:

- Sends it's argument (string) to the OS clipboard
- Reads the contents of the clipboard as string value
- Evals an s-expression from the clipboard

It's pretty old code, but has only java dependencies, so still works if you copy it into a namespace of your own.

**Import and Export as CSV**

Use [clojure.data.csv](https://github.com/clojure/data.csv)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible save data into text files while at the REPL. You can them use a text editor of your choice to process it further. For example

```
user=> (def v (into [] (range 100)))
#'user/v
user=> v
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]
user=> (spit "c:\\temp\\blah.txt" (with-out-str (prn *1)))
nil
user=> (slurp "c:\\temp\\blah.txt")
"[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]\n"
```